# Setting up SPARQL with C++

Tags: sparql

I am beginning to research SPARQL and I like the querying syntax very much. One thing I haven't seen yet is a way to make SPARQL queries from a C++ application. Is there a way to do this without having it go through an HTTP protocol or SQL or another database software? Can the data store be defined in a file, uploaded into memory, and updated as the state of the program changes?

Comment: What about using a good gold search engine with search term "SPARQL c++" to find APIs/tools? In any case, this is a bad question for Stackoverflow.

Comment: I wish such a search produces satisfactory answers but most results are APIs for languages like Java and .NET languages. I was hoping there's a way to integrate SPARQL for c++ applications to make queries and update the data store.

Comment: I don't know, maybe http://librdf.org/ .